# Use set 1 of a database to get set 2 of a different database in combination

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this for database A:

```
SELECT uid FROM user_id where this = :this
```

With those uid i want to get data from database B with the following query

```
SELECT name FROM users where uid = :uid_table1
```

How can I do this in 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge. there is no way to make one query do different parts of its work on different databases - a query is sent to a database. Any code you write would have to send one query to each database even if you did somehow make it into a single statement in some glue language.

As an analogy:

> I have two tasks.
>
> Get the definition of "umbrella" from the newest print edition of the
>   Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary.
>
> Look up the definition of each word in the previous definition in the
>   newest print OED.

While it is possible to rephrase that as a single sentence, equivalent to sagi's answer or the use of some glue language:

> Look up each word from the newest print Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary's definition of Umbrella in the newest print OED.

It would not be possible to execute that task without opening at least one copy of each book.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN()` :

```
SELECT name 
FROM Table2 t
WHERE t.uid IN(SELECT s.uid FROM Table1
               WHERE this = :this)
```

I assume by database you mean a table?

Alternatively , you can join:

```
SELECT name 
FROM Table2 t
JOIN Table1 s
 ON(s.uid = t.uid)
WHERE s.this = :this
```

Comment: I'm talking about different databases, not different tables ;)